What are the drawbacks of using the phase shift method (Hilbert Transformer) for SSB modulation?
The phase shift method (Hilbert Transformer) can be used for single sideband (SSB) generation. The box marked (−)/   is a /  phase shifter, which delays the phase of every spectral component by /. Hence, it is a Hilbert Transformer.
An ideal phase shifter is also unrealizable. It is easy to build a circuit to shift the phase of a single frequency component by /. But a device to achieve this phase shift for all the spectral components over a band of frequencies is unrealizable. We can, at best, approximate it over a finite band.

I think all baseband signals are finite in band, then where is the problem? give me please examples of signals that cannot be used with this circuit, and thus are not suitable with SSB modulation and needs other types of modulation.

Why there is a problem with achieving the phase shift with all the spectral components?




Re 2) A Hilbert Transformer is infinitely non-causal. If you want to phase shift 1Hz by 90 deg you need to delay by 0.25 s  If you need to phase shift 1 mHz your delay becomes over 4 minutes, etc. For 1 nHz it takes 8 years. The lower the frequency the larger the wait and there is no bound unless you limit the bandwidth

If you get to define the protocol, is there any reason to do anything but a complex exponential modulation (frequency shift) followed by moderate filtering for modulation (reverse for demod)?

I personally don't think that there's a problem with using the Hilbert Transformer to create an analytic signal to digitally heterodyne it up to some IF frequency.  But you'll need to put up with a little delay to do a good job of it.

An example of common signals that cannot be used with this circuit as the modulator itself is any complex baseband modulation where the quadrature component is independent of the in-phase component. This includes most modern waveforms including QPSK, QAM, etc. This is because the “Q” or quadrature component is completely independent of the “I” or in-phase component rather than being related by the Hilbert Transform as shown above for the $m(t)$ signal. For those waveforms we can still use the Hilbert on the narrow band carrier frequency as shown and then drive the I and Q components into each multiplier (mixer) directly. This is the form of the “IQ modulator”. We can also use the circuit above for any of these waveforms once modulated to be a frequency translator from a IF or intermediate frequency to RF or radio frequency and with that simplify some of the other filtering that would be needed.
If you are doing true “Single Sideband  Modulation” which is an analog modulation technique from 100 years ago not in high use today (still used by amateur radio enthusiasts but I don’t know of other practical applications), the modulation waveform does not extend to DC and is band limited and there is no issue in implementing the modulator and would be trivial to do so digitally as long as we can trade complexity and delay for the bandwidth and performance needed.  For this, the analog waveform would be modulated to one side of the carrier frequency as an AM modulation.
Hilbert Transformers can not be implemented to cover all frequencies and they don’t pass DC. To cover all frequencies the impulse response would need to be infinitely long and hence is unrealizable. However we can cover any band of frequencies we need and come as close to DC as needed at the expense of filter complexity and delay. As mentioned, when the Hilbert is just on a single higher frequency carrier frequency, its implementation is trivial.

@ Dan Boschen In reality, signals consist of a wide range of frequencies, and each frequency component can behave differently when passed through a physical circuit.  I think that the physical components such as capacitors and inductors exhibit frequency-dependent behavior: The impedance of reactive components changes with frequency. For instance, capacitive reactance decreases with increasing frequency while inductive reactance increases. This results in different phase shifts for different frequencies. Is this explanation true or not?

@Noha Yes capacitors and inductors are frequency dependent. Pure resistors are not. The impedance of an inductor for example is $j \omega L$ which is 90° at all frequencies with an increasing mag vs f. When combined with a resistor as a series R shunt C circuit, that circuit becomes $R/(R+j\omega L)$ and now you get a frequency dependent phase (and a high pass filter). We can do the same with digital filters. Ultimately a shift in the time domain is a phase in the frequency domain as given by the Fourier Transform of a delay: $x(t-\tau) \leftrightarrow X(f)e^{-j2\pi f \tau}$.  Did that help?

@ Dan Boschen Thus, regarding the question : Why there is a problem with the Hilbert Transformer method when applied to wide-band signals, i.e suitable only with signals having finite small band. The answer can be: The physical components such as capacitors and inductors exhibit frequency-dependent behavior. The impedance of reactive components changes with frequency. Right?

@ Dan Boschen regarding the first point, can we say that wide-band signals like TV signals can not be used with the phase shift Hilbert transformer method, and thus cannot be transmitted using SSB modulation?

@Noha Analog olor TV signals as you know them are phase modulations and hence need the in-phase component for signalling, so a single sideband is not enough. Digital TV signals are QAM  or higher PSK modulations, and are included in "most modern wafeorms" as mentioned by Dan

@Noha I have implemented analog components called “quadrature hybrids” or “90 degree splitters” with decades of bandwidth (my first job involved learning how to design and build all sorts of analog RF components using these). It need not be narrow bandwidth, the trade space is complexity and overall time delay (and that applies to digital or analog solutions).

@ Dan Boschen I need a clear answer to the following please. Regarding the question : Why there is a problem with the Hilbert Transformer method when applied to wide-band signals, i.e suitable only with signals having finite small band. The answer can be: The physical components such as capacitors and inductors exhibit frequency-dependent behavior. The impedance of reactive components changes with frequency. Right?

@Noha as I explained there is no problem applying the Hilbert Transform to wideband signals- it is a trade space with delay and complexity: if you can afford the delay and complexity you can use it over any bandwidth that you can practically use (note how we can never actually observe “DC” either since we would need to observe for infinite time: so you can apply the Hilbert to all frequencies you can observe). This is in the final paragraph of my answer.

If you want more technical details on implementing Hilbert Transforms either digital or analog, please check out my presentation for the 2022 DSP Online Conference; if you sign up for this year’s conference you get access to all the archives. It’s a two hour presentation so much more info than I could provide here.

(What you can’t do with wideband signals is use a time delay to create the 90 degree phase shift, but what we can do is use phase tracking networks)

@ Dan Boschen A final comment please. Could you give me one possible hardware implementation for the Hilbert transformer and indicate the reason for delay and complexity with signals having large number of frequency components?

@Noha if you are looking for a DSP implementation, this would be the site for that but please post it as a new question. If you a want an implementation with L’s and C’s or other hardware based approaches for an analog Hilbert, the Electronics StackExchange would be more appropriate for that

//"... there is no problem applying the Hilbert Transform to wideband signals..."// - - - - - the only problem is the cost in computation, size of the coefficient table, and real-time delay.  You need a really long FIR to make the Hilbert transformer amplitude response decently flat at low frequencies.

One drawback of the standard FIR approach to Hilbert transform filters is that if you wish to hold the 90 degree phase condition down to very low frequencies (like 20Hz for audio), the filter length becomes very long.  An alternate approach is to use two parallel chains of allpass filters where the output phases are very close to 90 degrees apart over a specified frequency range.  Typically an optimizer is required to design the filters. The savings in MIPs is usually very significant.
